# Layout cut at the bottom in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

I have a ScrollView in my app and inside it I have created a Linear Layout which contains various elements but the problem is this my  buttons on bottom are not displayed properly. They are cut off at bottom. I have used padding and margin but nothing has been happened. Below is my layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/light_gray">


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp10">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp20"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp20"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp30"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgArticleImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp140"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp15"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/banner" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_grey_border_white_bg">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/dp5"
                android:text="@string/title"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />


            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/ettxtLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/txtTitle"
                android:padding="@dimen/dp5"
                app:counterEnabled="true"
                app:counterMaxLength="100"
                app:counterTextAppearance="@style/TextLimitStyle">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/etTitile"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp80"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:maxLength="100" />


            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp20"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_grey_border_white_bg">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitleDes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/dp5"
                android:text="@string/start_writing"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />


            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/ettxtLayoutDes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/txtTitleDes"
                android:padding="@dimen/dp5"
                app:counterEnabled="true"
                app:counterMaxLength="1200"
                app:counterTextAppearance="@style/TextLimitStyle">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/etDescription"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp140"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:overScrollMode="always"
                    android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical" />


            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layNew"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSave_draft"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp10"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp20"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dp10"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/dp10"
                android:text="@string/save_draft"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnPublish_article"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dp10"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/dp10"
                android:text="@string/publish_your_article"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"

                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layUpdate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnDiscardChanges"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp10"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp20"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dp10"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/dp10"
                android:text="@string/discard_changes"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSaveChanges"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dp10"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/dp10"
                android:text="@string/save_changes"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"

                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>


<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

`

[image: Screenshot of layout]

Can anyone suggest me what I have missed?

Comment: can you plz attach image.

Comment: remove android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp10" in scrollview

Answer (score 1):

Wrap up another `LinearLayout` under the `ScrollView` and give

`paddingBottom` to the **Second child (the second LinearLayout)**

so add this to the *added* linearLayout :-

```
 android:paddingBottom="20dp"
```

Correct order for padding :-

```
  ScrollView
     ||
    LinearLayout X- X -- > padding Bottom wont be applied  
          ||
        LinearLayout with paddingBottom -- > is applicable
```

**Note** :- `paddingBottom` and `marginBottom` cannot be applied to the *immediate* child of the `ScrollView`.

Comment: But Android Developer doesn't use paddingBottom in scrollview child

Comment: i am saying that-- if he uses `paddingBottom` it will solve the issue !! @JyotiJK **And to do that he need to add another layout to the child layout**

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp10"

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp10">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp30" into your LinearLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_gray">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp10">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp20"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp20"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp30"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp30">
```